# How do I make an animated 360º spin from photos of an object?

Tags: web, photos

I need to photograph and animate a cell phone into a 360º web spin for a client. I would need to capture 40 images sequenced and "stitch" them together for a final Flash animation for their website.
What software/hardware would you recommend?

Comment: The answer by DaveParillo will only get you a 'slideshow' of your images, which happen to be taken in a 360 degree circle. With fades in between that may be good enough for you, but it is not 'stitched'. Google for 'make panoramic movie', this will e.g. lead you to http://www.panoramas.dk/panorama/software.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).  Open a cmd window and cd to where your images are:

```
convert frame*.jpeg mymovie.flv
```

will convert all the images into a single movie file.  You may need to install '[delegates](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)' depending on what you wan to convert into. If you need to insert a delay between frames:

```
convert -delay 30 frame*.jpeg mymovie.flv
```

The delay units are *ticks /  ticks per second*  - you specify the ticks.  The default ticks per sec = 100.

[This page](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/) goes into far greater detail, using a combination of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), and imagemagick.